# why it won't check the other if statements ... (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

It won't check my if statements, I need it to check all of them.. in order to not break the code... otherwise the "Bot" will crash as it's not possible without those checks to continue..

Any ideas?

```
if (args[1] < 1) return message.reply("You have to delete at least one message!")
// it's just checking this statement:
if (!args[1]) return message.reply("Please enter the amount of messages to clear!")

if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please type a real number!")

if (args[1] > 100) return message.reply("You can't remove more than 100 messages!")
```

Comment: try to be more specific and show what you tried. Did you use curly braces? if() {}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the `return` statement for each `if` conditional which means as soon as the condition is met, the function will exit with the return statement.
Removing the `return` statement from all will allow the program run til the end without interruption.

Answer (score 0):

You could do all you condition with array of object method

1. you need declare your condition and error message on array with object
2. Then check with [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check all the `errorCondition` are fails
3. If you have any error condition detected then display with else via forEach loop

```js
const arr = 5;
let errorConditions = [{
  status: arr > 5,
  msg: "not allowed or something" // your message
},{
  status: isNaN(arr),
  msg: "not allowed nan" 
}];

if(errorConditions.every(({status}) => !status)){
  console.log("all error condition fails so executed successfully")
}else{
  console.log('err')
  errorConditions.forEach(({status,msg})=>{
     if(status){
        //do stuff like message.reply(msg)
        console.log(msg)
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!